# No response from terminal with hhvm command

Tags: php, virtual-machine, hhvm

when I input hhvm command. Terminal deoesn't response.

[environment]
Ubuntu 15.10
HipHop VM 3.11.0
Composer 1.0-dev

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:/var/www/html$ cat test2.hh
<?hh
require_once 'vender/facebook/xhp-lib/init.php';
echo <p>test</p>;
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:/var/www/html$ sudo hhvm test2.hh
```

Why??

If I remove .hhconfig file and input "touch .hhconfig" command, "hhvm test.hh" success one time.
But, I re-try "hhvm test.hh" and no-response....

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:/var/www/html/project$ sudo rm .hhconfig 
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:/var/www/html/project$ sudo touch .hhconfig
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:/var/www/html/project$ sudo hhvm test.hh
<p>test</p>vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:/var/www/html/project$ 
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:/var/www/html/project$ sudo hhvm test.hh
^Cvagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:/var/www/html/project$
```

I guess some service got lock of .hhconfig file...
Does someone give me hint??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect you are running into [this issue with `hh_client`](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/6671), which affects `hhvm` since the latter calls into the former. We are investigating it now, and will release 3.11.1 to fix it when we pin down the problem.

In the meantime, you can use the 3.9 LTS, or you can try passing `-d hhvm.hack.lang.auto_typecheck=0` when invoking `hhvm`. (Though if you do the latter, make sure to stop doing that when 3.11.1 is out, since it removes protection against Hack type errors sneaking into your code!)